# Union and intersection of images

Tags: number-theory, fourier-analysis

For any pair of integer-valued functions $f$ and $g$ defined on the integers, does there exist an integer-valued function $h$ on the integers such that $h(\mathbb{Z})=f(\mathbb{Z})\cap g(\mathbb{Z})$, or such that $h(\mathbb{Z})=f(\mathbb{Z})\cup g(\mathbb{Z})$?  Of course, we might simply define $h$ as desired, but I'm looking for a definition of $h$ in terms of elementary functions.

I think that if one can find sequences of all even numbers, except for the occurrence of odd numbers at a regular frequency, then you could do it.  Or maybe Fourier Analysis could help.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for.  Maybe $h(2n)=f(n),h(2n+1)=g(n)$?  Something like that?

Comment: Note:  my example gives the union.  You can't give the intersection in general...if the intersection is empty then no such $h$ exists.

Comment: DK what you are asking. A function from $A$ to $B$ is a certain kind of subset of $A\times B.$ What are you trying to say when you write $f\cup g$ and $f\cap g$?